# How to insert data from the function into another table using procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, table-functions

I would like to insert the return type of a function into a table using a procedure. Function is returning a collection as its output. We are calling that function from a select statement inside the procedure to validate and store it's results.

Let me give u the output result.

```
Create table customer
(Cust_id number,
Address varchar2(10),
Pincode number);

Create type t1 is object
(Cust_id number,
Address varchar2 (10),
Pincode number);

Create type t is table of t1;

Create function fn1
Return t
Is
i t := t();
Cursor C1 is
Select t1(cust_id, 
address,pincode)
From customer;
Begin
Open C1;
I.extend();
Fetch C1 bulk collect into i;
Close c1;
Return i;
End ;
```

---

Now I'm calling this function inside a procedure using select statement inside a procedure

```
Create procedure PS1
Is
Begin
For i in (select * from 
table(fsn1))
Loop
If i.pincode is not null
Then insert into tb1 values 
 (i.cust_id,i.pincode);
End if;
Commit;
 End loop;
End;
```

If i tried running this procedure as an anonymous block, it is working. however I need to run this only as a proc/function.

Kindly help me in this.

Comment: "I need to run this only as a proc/function." - what happened when you tried to do that? That's what your last piece of code represents, right? Were there any problems? Errors? Which ones?

Comment: And a side note: do not fetch rows that you do not need. Filter out them in the `select` statement. Also if there's no any processing in the loop, you may use `insert into tbl1(cust_id, pincode) select cust_id, pincode from table(fn1()) where pincode is not null`. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f7655db7435d454818f0e46f36ebb793)

Comment: @Littlefoot there was no error. Block is compiling successfully but there will be no data in the target table. If i ran the same code as anonymous block, it will load the data into the table.

Comment: That code only created a procedure. Now you have to **run** it: `begin ps1; end;`

Comment: @astentx Thanks for the response. However I need to load this using a plsql object since this process needs to be automated. also, as i mentioned, it can be loaded as anonymous block or insert statement but if i use the same inside a proc , it is not working..

Comment: Automation doesn't make any difference. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fd1778fa277ff86a983d89838c2cedbf)